# Maven build process gets killed when compiling GWT

Tags: maven, gwt, maven-3, sh, ubuntu-10.04

My Maven build process gets killed at the OS level when it tries to compile GWT so the build does not finish and does not report either success or fail.  I ran `mvn3` with the -X option and here is where it happens:

```
[DEBUG] Execute command :
/bin/sh -c /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.26/jre/bin/java -Xmx512m -classpath <really_long_classpath> com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler -gen <path_loc> -logLevel INFO -style OBF -war <war_path> -localWorkers 1 <module_path>
./build.sh: line 2: 24139 Killed                  mvn3 -X clean install blah blah
```

When I take the command out of Maven and run it solo, I get the same failure.  However, when I just run Java without `/bin/sh -c`, GWT compiles fine.

Why does Maven use `/bin/sh`?  My default shell on `Ubuntu 10.04` is `bash`.

Comment: You system probably told you why in one of the systems' logs. Probably at /var/log/messages or some other file in /var/log/. You can list all files ordered by time, latest last, by executing "ls -ltr /var/log/"

Answer (score 2):

There is no reason for the command working without the 'sh -c', but who knows.

The `mvn` command is just a shell script which set the appropriate java environment to run java with the maven class. It uses `/bin/sh` because it is set in the first line of the script. If you want to use `bash` just change the first line of the script `!/bin/sh` by `!/bin/bash`.

Anyway, it seems your ubuntu is killing the compiler because it is taking more resources that it is allowed. Take a look to your /var/log/syslog file to see the reason why the kernel killed the build.

1- Try to reconfigure `gwt-maven` plugin in your `pom.xml` so as it only launches a worker

```
 <localWorkers>1</localWorkers>
```

2- try to increase memory of the gwt compiler process

```
 <extraJvmArgs>-Xmx1g</extraJvmArgs>
```

3- try to run maven with more memory

```
 $ export MAVEN_OPTS="-Xmx1g"
```

4- take a look to your shell `ulimit` and increase the appropriate parameters

```
 $ ulimit -a
```